# Retrieve css property scaleX using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to print out the properties of a particular `div` using  JQuery.
I would like the various `css` properties to appear in an information panel on the screen.

I am trying to display `scaleX` but having a lot of difficulty. This is my code currently:

```
//Size Control
$("#slider").change(function () {
    size = $("#slider").val();
    //Update the size of box while dragging
    b1.css({
        "-webkit-transform": "scaleX(" + size / 10 + ") scaleY(" + size / 10 + ") rotate(" + rotation + "deg) rotateX("+ rotateX + "deg) rotateY("+ rotateY + "deg) skew("+ skewX + "deg," + skewY + "deg)",
    });

    $("#sizeInfo").text("Size: " + b1.css("-webkit-transform"));

});
```

HTML

```
 <div id="b1"></div>
```

Output in info panel

**matrix3d(-0.6998933866094739, -0.012216684506098372, 0.0000000000000001224646799147353, 0, 0.012216684506098542, -0.6998933866094739, 0.0000000000000001224646799147353, 0, 0.00000000000000008421610720791067, 0.00000000000000008720833192322797, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is this _difficultly_ of which you speak? Where are things going wrong?

Comment: This difficulty of which I speak is that currently this line of code  `$("#sizeInfo").text("Size: " + b1.css("-webkit-transform"));` does not output the value of `scaleX`

Comment: @Javacadabra what is `b1`; what are `rotateX` et. al.?

Comment: just a basic `div` I've added the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.css` wraps `window.getComputedStyle` which uses the *computed* style rather than the raw style information.  You can use the style property on the element to get the actual string:

```
b1.get(0).style.WebkitTransform
```